# How can I partition a Macbook 2,1 so that it can install the bootloader?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, bootloader, macbook

I have a Macbook 2,1 which has the Intel Core 2 Duo processor but only 1Gb of RAM. I had previously installed Ubuntu 14.04 but lost this installation when I cloned another Mac 10.6 install onto it.

Now I want to put Ubuntu back but the DVD ROM only works briefly when the computer is stone cold and it doesn't work long enough to install an OS.

My solution was to try a USB but it wouldn't detect the device when I option-booted. This was fixed by adding a 32 bit EFI (A32.efi)bootloader to my USB. Now I can boot Ubuntu 16.04 from the USB but the installation always fails at the point when it has to install the bootloader, even when I erase the HDD and let it choose its own partition table.

Has anyone had a similar problem and solved it?

Answer (score 0):

OK I fixed it, firstly by using a different iso, I used Ubuntu 14.04 instead of Ubuntu Mate 16.04. Although the installer behaved in a similar way, it did not crash after failing to install the bootloader. I continued the installation without installing a bootloader and then used the instructions here [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)  to install and run Boot repair from the live disk. This did the trick and I am back with an Ubuntu Macbook!